# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const News = (props)=>{
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    const [totalResults, setTotalResults] = useState(0)
    
    const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    } 

    const updateNews = async ()=> {
        props.setProgress(10);
        const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${props.country}&category=${props.category}&apiKey=${props.apiKey}&page=${page}&pageSize=${props.pageSize}`; 
        setLoading(true)
        let data = await fetch(url);
        props.setProgress(30);
        let parsedData = await data.json()
        props.setProgress(70);
        setArticles(parsedData.articles)
        setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults)
        setLoading(false)
        props.setProgress(100);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = `${capitalizeFirstLetter(props.category)} - NewsPanda`;
        updateNews(); 
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])


    const fetchMoreData = async () => {   
        const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${props.country}&category=${props.category}&apiKey=${props.apiKey}&page=${page+1}&pageSize=${props.pageSize}`;
        setPage(page+1) 
        let data = await fetch(url);
        let parsedData = await data.json()
        setArticles(articles.concat(parsedData.articles))`enter code here`
        setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults)
      };
 
        return (
            <>
                <h1 className="text-center" style={{ margin: '35px 0px', marginTop: '90px' }}>NewsPanda - Top {capitalizeFirstLetter(props.category)} Headlines</h1>
                {loading && <Spinner />}
                <InfiniteScroll
                    dataLength={articles.length} /////here i'm getting this error/////
                    next={fetchMoreData}
                    hasMore={articles.length !== totalResults}
                    loader={<Spinner/>}
                > 
                    <div className="container">
                         
                    <div className="row">
                        {articles.map((element) => {
                            return <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                                <NewsItem title={element.title ? element.title : ""} description={element.description ? element.description : ""} imageUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} author={element.author} date={element.publishedAt} source={element.source.name} />
                            </div>
                        })}
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                </InfiniteScroll>
            </>
        )
    
}
```

While forking my code from github to codesandbox, it is showing the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" in codesandbox. But i have defined articles above.

I really don't know what is happening here. Anyone got a solution for this?

It is showing an error at line `dataLength = {articles.length};`

Comment: Can you add the codesandbox link?

Comment: Most likely `parsedData.articles` is undefined. You should `console.log` it

Comment: The answer is probably in the browser dev tools network tab.  I would guess the api call is blocked.

Comment: heres the link https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-resonance-61pd8z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving an error as a response from `newsapi.org`

```
{
  code: "corsNotAllowed"
  message: "Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer 
  plan, except from localhost."
  status: "error"
}
```

Your `News` component is expecting `articles` to be an array and breaks if it is not. You should only add `parsedData.articles` into state conditionally, or else it could be `undefined`.

```
  const updateNews = async () => {
    setError(null)
    props.setProgress(10);
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${props.country}&category=${props.category}&apiKey=${props.apiKey}&page=${page}&pageSize=${props.pageSize}`;
    setLoading(true);
    let data = await fetch(url);
    props.setProgress(30);
    let parsedData = await data.json();

    if (parsedData.status !== 'error') {
      props.setProgress(70);
      setArticles(parsedData.articles);
      setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults);
      props.setProgress(100);
    } else {
      props.setProgress(0);
      setError('Something went wrong')
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

[image: Edit morning-pond-1ur0ey]

Answer (score -1):

In code an object has to be defined.

In your code articles probably not defined thus length cannot be resolved.

```
{ articles.length ...
```

Two things you need to do is see that articles indeed properly set as an array. And you can add a validation for articles variable

```
{ articles?.length
```

The validation can lead to other errors so you better validate your variables as early in your code as you can.